# Help to show if this is correct $\int_{0}^{\infty}{(e^{-2x}+2e^{-x})\cos^2(x/ 2)\sin(x)\over x}\mathrm dx={9\pi\over 16}$

Tags: calculus, integration

We have this integral

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{(e^{-2x}+2e^{-x})\cos^2\left({x\over 2}\right)\sin(x)\over x}\mathrm dx={9\pi\over 16}\tag1$$

$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ rearrange to get

$\cos^2\left({x\over 2}\right)={\sin^2(x)\over 4\sin^2\left({x\over 2}\right)}$ now substitute this into $(1)$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-2x}+2e^{-x}\over x}{\sin^3(x)\over 4\sin^2\left({x\over 2}\right)}\mathrm dx\tag2$$

$2u=x$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-4u}+2e^{-2u}\over u}{\sin^3(2u)\over 8\sin^2\left({u}\right)}\mathrm du\tag3$$

Using $\sin(2x)={2\tan(x)\over 1+\tan^2(x)}$ sub into $(3)$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-4u}+2e^{-2u}\over u}{8\tan^3(u)\over (1+\tan^2(u))^3}{1\over 8\sin^2(u)}\mathrm du\tag4$$

Simplified to

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-4u}+2e^{-2u}\over u}{\tan(u)\cos^4(u)}\mathrm du\tag5$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-4u}+2e^{-2u}\over u}{\sin(u)\cos^3(u)}\mathrm du\tag6$$

Using $\cos^3(u)={3\over 4}\cos(u)+{1\over 4}\cos(3u)$

$${3\over 8}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-4u}+2e^{-2u}\over u}\sin(2u)\mathrm du+{1\over 4}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-4u}+2e^{-2u}\over u}\sin(u)\cos(3u)\mathrm du\tag7$$

So far nothing is really  leading to proving this integral.

I need  help on how to show if this integral is correct or not.

Comment: A not-so-fun way to do this is to use Euler's formula to make everything into an exponential and then pound away at it until you get an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{(e^{-2x}+2e^{-x})\cos^2\left({x\over 2}\right)\sin(ax)\over x}\mathrm dx.$$
Using
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\cos(bx)\mathrm dx=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(a)&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-2x}+2e^{-x})\cos^2\left({x\over 2}\right)\cos(ax)\mathrm dx\\
&=&\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-2x}+2e^{-x})(1+\cos(x))\cos(ax)\mathrm dx\\
&=&\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-2x}+2e^{-x})\cos(ax)\mathrm dx+\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-2x}+2e^{-x})\cos(x)\cos(ax)\mathrm dx\\
&=&\frac12\bigg(\frac{2}{4+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+a^2}\bigg)+\frac14\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-2x}+2e^{-x})\bigg[\cos((1+a)x)+\cos((1-a)x)\bigg]\mathrm dx\\
&=&\frac12\bigg(\frac{2}{4+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+a^2}\bigg)+\frac12\bigg[\frac{1}{(a-1)^2+4}+\frac{1}{2 ((a+1)^2+1)}+\frac{1}{(a+1)^2+4}+\frac{1}{2 \left((a-1)^2+1\right)}\bigg],
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
I(1)&=&\frac12\int_0^1\bigg(\frac{2}{4+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+a^2}\bigg)\mathrm da+\frac12\int_0^1\bigg[\frac{1}{(a-1)^2+4}+\frac{1}{2 ((a+1)^2+1)}+\frac{1}{(a+1)^2+4}+\frac{1}{2 \left((a-1)^2+1\right)}\bigg]\mathrm da\\
&=&\frac12(\frac{\pi}{4}+\arctan\frac12)+\frac12(\pi+4\arctan 2)\\
&=&\frac1{16}(3\pi+8\arctan\frac12+4\arctan 2).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This sorta helps... We can get a closed form for $I'(a)$, but it is not pretty... rational function with degree 6 in denominator and 4 in numerator. At that point you have a pretty messy integral to work with.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, see my update.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for the update. +1 for sure!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{%
> \pars{\expo{-2x} + 2\expo{-x}}\cos^2\pars{x/2}\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x =
> {9 \over 16}\,\pi:\
> {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}{%
\pars{\expo{-2x} + 2\expo{-x}}\cos^2\pars{x/2}\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\pars{\expo{-2x} + 2\expo{-x}}{1 + \cos\pars{x} \over 2}
{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\pars{\expo{-2x} + 2\expo{-x}}\,{2\sin\pars{x} + \sin\pars{2x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\pars{\expo{-2x} + 2\expo{-x}}\,{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x +
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\pars{\expo{-x} + 2\expo{-x/2}}\,{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-2x}\,{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x +
{5 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x}\,{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x +
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x/2}\,{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> Note that

\begin{align}
&\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\alpha x}\,{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
\right\vert_{\ \alpha\ >\ 0} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\alpha x}\,{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic k x}
\,\dd k\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-\pars{\alpha - \ic k}x}\,\dd x\,\dd k
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}{\dd k \over \alpha - \ic k} =
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}{\alpha + \ic k \over k^{2} + \alpha^{2}}\,\dd k =
\int_{0}^{1/\alpha}{\dd k \over k^{2} + 1} =
\arctan\pars{1 \over \alpha}
\end{align}

> \eqref{1} becomes

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}{%
\pars{\expo{-2x} + 2\expo{-x}}\cos^2\pars{x/2}\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2}\bracks{%
\arctan\pars{1 \over 2} + {5 \over 2}\,\arctan\pars{1} + \arctan\pars{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\pars{{\pi \over 2} + {5 \over 2}\,{\pi \over 4}} =
\bbx{{9 \over 16}\,\pi}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{\arctan\pars{x} =
> {\pi \over 2}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{x} - \arctan\pars{1 \over x} \implies
> \arctan\pars{1 \over 2} + \arctan\pars{2} = {\pi \over 2}}$.